# How to install a compiled driver (module) in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, audio

I have a Chuwi Hi12 tablet (x86_64 processor) and I installed ArchLinux on it. I'm trying to make sound work using default driver, but I couldn't. So I downloaded a C written driver from here:

[linux-chwhi12/es8316.c](https://github.com/kernins/linux-chwhi12/blob/master/sound/soc/codecs/es8316.c)

I compiled it with the system included makefile and I obtained the .ko file. I don't know how should I continue from here, so I'm asking in this forum.

Thank you very much for reading and answering

______________________________________________________________-

EDIT.
I tried to insert the module with insmod, but it says that the resouce is busy. I don't know how to manage it. Here are modules that refers to es8316:

```
snd_soc_sst_byt_cht_es8316 16384 0 - Live 0x          (null)
snd_soc_es8316 40960 1 - Live 0x          (null)
snd_soc_core 286720 3 snd_soc_sst_byt_cht_es8316,snd_soc_es8316,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform, Live 0x          (null)
snd_pcm 135168 6 snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_byt_cht_es8316,snd_soc_es8316,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine, Live 0x          (null)
```

These are default drivers installed with Arch Linux, but they doesn't work, so I'm try to install the driver I shown

Comment: You [write a PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages) and have pacman install it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing the module, use `sudo insmod <module_name>.ko`.  Once you've got it installed, the .ko should live in `/usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/`, which will allow you to do `sudo modprobe <module_name>`

@jasonwryan is the most correct though, you should write up a PKGBUILD.  I haven't packaged a kernel module before in arch, but [the wiki has a great resource on it, as always](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support#PKGBUILD)

Comment: Sorry. I can't test it. I reinstalled Arch and now it doesn't compile... I will ask in this forum

Comment: Ok. Now I can continue. When I try to insert the module, it says that the resource is busy (I guess by other module)

Comment: Check if your module is already loaded with `lsmod`

Comment: I have checked it. I have add an update

Comment: you need to remove the module and all depending modules with `rmmod` before you can load your replacement

Comment: Ok. I think it's working, but sound doesn't work. I will ask in other question